# SkipWhile to check if a condition holds continuously in RxJava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactive

There are several `Observable`s of a continuous stream of `accelerometer` data. In one of the `Observable`s I'd like to sample the data and receive only about 5 a second, or in effect, skip x elements.

I tried `sample` and `skipWhile`. `Sample` simply queues the data and gives it in the order sent be the emitter with a delay.
`skipWhile` is closer to what I need, but it checks for the condition only once. Once `skipWhile` returns `false` the stream continues and then never checks for the condition.

```
.skipWhile(imuSensorEvent -> {
    return imuSensorEvent.getTimestamp() - last < 100 * 1000000;
})
```

How would I use something like `skipWhile` and always check for the condition?

Comment: Sounds like you do need [`sample(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#sample-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to get up to 5 values per second

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I tried, but as mentioned in the question, `sample` queues the emitted data and is received in the same order but with a delay; in effect it is not dropping the values in between.

Comment: This samples properly for me: https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/c187983b43a795e9777ac58189b8bc24